# Troubleshooting loading an API

Tags: php, json, api, jsonp, etsy

I'm working on using the Etsy API and have been trying to complete this online tutorial but haven't been able to load any of the data successfully:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/10/01/custom-products-webpage-layout-via-the-etsy-api/

When I load the page, it creates the cache file but the page is blank.

This is my first venture into APIs and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot what the problem might be. It seems like all of the code with loading it into the PHP webpage should work ok.

I've read about a few issues people have had using the Etsy API beacuse of the json cross-domain policy, so I'm wondering if that might be the issue, or if there might be authentication that is required.

I created a pastebin of the code from the tutorial here:
http://pastebin.com/RVDzjG4B

Answer (score 0):

After checking the docs and the API, I got this.

```
API requests must be made over HTTPS.
```

Change your links to use `https://`.